# how to resolve promise pending from async function within express get call

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I have an api call created using express.get() which inside also calls an async function to return an axios.get() request.  The getTwitterData() async function only returns promise pending. How do I resolved this?

```
'use strict';
 const axios = require('axios');
 const express = require('express');
 const app = express();
 const jwt = require('express-jwt');
 const jwks = require('jwks-rsa');
 const cors = require('cors');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(cors());

 const auth = `OAuth oauth_consumer_key="D1X5bwx6tF5rNcC9J6iPDfhqP",oauth_token="4686534691-KcECHY2gBOtIqSAKrCYVFDKpOgkb1yNw5e3CCwk",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1521437993",oauth_nonce="peQkEX9wZZM",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="U%2FG%2BLtMLOWQPUO3tHmwZk0iBrgY%3D"`;
 const url = `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=singer`;


 app.get('/api/twitter/data', (req, res) => {
   const tData = getTweetData().then((data)=>{
     return data;
   });
   console.log("tData: ", tData);
   res.json({tData});
 })

 async function getTweetData() {
   try{
     const data = await axios.get(url, { headers: { Authorization: auth }                     });
     return data;
   }catch(err){
     console.log(err);
   }
 }

 app.listen(3333);

 console.log('Listening on localhost:3333');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `getTweetData()` is infact returning a promise which is why `tData` is appearing as promise pending. An async function will return a Promise, you can learn more about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Without using async again we could take below

```
 app.get('/api/twitter/data', (req, res) => {
   const tData = getTweetData().then((data)=>{
     return data;
   });
   console.log("tData: ", tData);
   res.json({tData});
 })
```

and change it to handle the responding data which you will get when the promise resolves.

```
app.get('/api/twitter/data', (req, res) => {
       getTweetData().then((data)=>{
         //we have the data so just send the res here
         res.json({data});
       });
     })
```

Another alternative would be to change the anonymous function your using for the Express API endpoint to use async. Note: I am not sure if Express supports this, I am simply demonstrating how one would write this using async functions

```
   app.get('/api/twitter/data', async (req, res) => {
       const tData = await getTweetData()
       console.log("tData: ", tData);
       res.json({tData});
     })
```

Comment: The second app.get with the async does work, but when I call res.json({tData}) i get this "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: The data is already in JSON format so is there something else I call?

Comment: So I needed to access the data as tData.data.  I didnt realize this was an object with keys being returned.

Comment: @AustinBorn If this worked please mark the answer as correct. Thanks